# Javascript - Converting a date to time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the difference between NOW and when an item was posted. How can I do this? Currently I am only getting monster big results which are not correct..

Goal:

How many seconds ago was this posted?

```
var thisTime = jQuery.now()/1000;
var postTime = new Date('2014-07-30 07:32:22')/1000;
var timeDiff = thisTime - postTime;

var text = timeDiff +'seconds ago';
```

Should return something like: timeDiff seconds ago.

Comment: You should try your code step by step, this would maybe hint at the date.getTime() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

```js
var thisTime = new Date().getTime()/1000;
var postTime = new Date('2014-08-01 12:20:22').getTime()/1000;
var timeDiff = thisTime - postTime;

var text = timeDiff +' seconds ago';
console.log(text);
```

`Date.getTime()` returns milliseconds since 1970/01/01 - to get seconds you have to divide by 1000. Then, you simply use substraction.